# Compare values from a form field value and a queryset value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my app the SignUp form looks like this:

**Forms.py**

```
class EmployeeSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=True, label='Select Company')
    c_code = forms.IntegerField(required=True)    
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save (self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_employee = True
        user.save()

        c_company = self.cleaned_data['company'][0]

        employee = Employee.objects.create(user=user, company=c_company)    
        return user
```

How can I compare the c_code with the company_code in my models.py and save the form only when both of them matches else throw an error?

**Models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.company_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```py
def clean_c_code(self):
    c_code = int(self.cleaned_data['c_code'])
    try:
        Company.objects.get(c_code=c_code)
    except Company.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError("Don't save")
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion but I want to compare the company code field in my models with the `c_code`  in my form and if they match only the save them

Comment: I've edited my answer but I don't really know if I understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: I answered my partial solution, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
@transaction.atomic
    def save (self):

        if self.cleaned_data['company'].company_code == self.cleaned_data['c_code']:
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.is_employee = True
            user.save()
            c_company = self.cleaned_data['company']
            employee = Employee.objects.create(user=user, company=c_company)
            return user
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Don't save")
```